# Importing a Namespace into a Generic Handler

Tags: asp.net

How am I supposed to import my own namespace into a generic handler (ashx file) ?

-- edit: Website not a web application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ashx file itself should contain code like:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="MyProject.MyHandlerClass" %>
```

And then your project will also contain a class file with that namespace and class:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyHandlerClass : IHttpHandler
    {
         public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) { ... }
    }
}
```